# Overrriding HitTestCore method for detecting multiple controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, overriding, hittest

I am creating a custom control which does hit testing on its children. I'm planning on overriding the `HitTestCore` method to return multiple controls which fall inside or intersects with a Geometric region. Just wondering if anyone else has tried this. Do you have any pointers for me? Or is there another way which I can do this (without actually overriding the `HitTestCore` method)? Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to get multiple controls seems like I didn't need to override the `HitTestCore` method.

I created a `HitTestFilterCallback` and whenever it hit on a `CheckBox` (which was the type of control I was hit testing) I saved it onto a list called `_hitTestResults`. But I'm not sure whether this is the right way to do this :S

Here is what I did:

```
HitTestFilterBehavior OnHitTestFilter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        if (target.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            _hitTestResults.Add(target as CheckBox); // add the hittest result
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren;
        }
        else
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;

    }
```